# How to compare and merge key values when there is a matching values in a ansible list

Tags: json, list, ansible, jinja2

I have below output, i want to compare `tunnel` value in a list and if it matches then corresponding  `custip` values have to be merged.
I have come across couple of posts in stack overflow but most of them are comparing two lists and merged the list if anything is in common found. Couldn't find the post to compare key values in single list and merge corresponding other key value.
I am new to ansible still in learning phase, i would really appricate to point me to right resources/example/any doc so that i can figure out or if provide solution that would be great. Thanks

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "custip": "192.168.10.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
        },
        {
            "custip": "192.168.20.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
        },
        {
            "custip": "1.1.1.1/32",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.10"
        },
        {
            "custip": "2.2.2.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.11"
        },
        {
            "custip": "3.3.3.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.11"
        }

    ]
}
```

if the `tunnel` vlaue matches then `custip` has to be merged/combined to get below output

desired/wanted output:

```
[
            {
                "custip": ["192.168.10.0/24","192.168.20.0/24"],
                "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
            },
            {
                "custip": ["1.1.1.1/32"],
                "tunnel": "tunnel.10"
            },
            {
                "custip": ["2.2.2.0/24",3.3.3.0/24],
                "tunnel": "tunnel.11"
            }

        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your original data structure is in a var named `the_list`, then the [`groupby` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#groupby) will do what you want, given a little massaging to put it back into the desired shape afterward

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {%- set results = [] -%}
        {%- for k, v in the_list | groupby("tunnel") -%}
        {%-  set _ = results.append({
            "tunnel": k,
            "custip": v | map(attribute="custip") | list
          }) -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ results }}
```

That `map(attribute="custip")` is due to the intermediate shape being

```json
        [
            "tunnel.5",
            [
                {
                    "custip": "192.168.10.0/24",
                    "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
                },
                {
                    "custip": "192.168.20.0/24",
                    "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
                }
            ]
        ]
```

so we need to reach into the `grouper.list` and pull out the interesting `custip` elements from it

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: @mdaniel thank you for your answer, follow up question - I have some tunnel values as null `tunnel: null` i am getting error `'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'AnsibleUnsafeText'"}` i tried inserting `{%- if v is not none -%}` inside for loop but that didn't hep, any suggestions ?

Comment: Two parts: obviously if you have influence over the generation of that data, don't introduce `null`; otherwise, if you don't have influence, and it's just given to you, then you'll need to massage the _input structure_ into the `groupby`, because that's the part which is failing, and set `tunnel` to some non-null value. There are a bunch of examples of doing the latter [in the ansible tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+update+dict)